I implemented microsoft GraphRag, how to trace local search result references back to source documents?
I indexed a csv file in which source_column is the name of the document and text_column is the relevant text.
After generating the answer, I want to know using which documents it generated the response.
I have access to the reports,entites,etc. But i want to check from which document it picked the answer.
